# UICollectionViewCell has left offset

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

In my Today Widget I use a `UICollectionView` with some different size cells in it.

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.vertical;
collectionView = UICollectionView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

I then create those cells with some placeholder colors for now:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if (pokemon.count == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            return CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 220)
        } else {
            return CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 110)
        }
    } else {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            return CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 110)
        } else {
            return CGSize.init(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 56)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (pokemon.count == 0) {
        return 2
    } else {
        return pokemon.count+1
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    }

    return cell
}
```

Now, what happens is that my cells have a left offset and I can't figure out why that is. I attached a screenshot of the behaviour. I tried setting the layout with the minimum distances included directly, but that didn't have any effect. Any ideas?

[image: a screenshot]

Comment: try-: collectionView = UICollectionView.(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout).This gives you default flow layout cell and you can resize cell in collection view size method. Moreover there is no need to call init everywhere. You create objects just like -: var a = Abc() and not Abc.init().

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that **automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets** is set to true. Try setting this to false in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: Like I said in my question; I already did. It didn’t work though.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. Please check my updated answer if it helps you.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it either.